# Is it ok to allocate released object again?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, alloc

if i did this

```
Object * myObject = [[Object alloc]init];
[myObject release];
```

is there anything wrong about allocating my object in next line

```
myObject = [[Object alloc]init];
```

again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem at all.
`[myobject release];` releases the object pointed at by `myObject`.

Later, `myobject = [[Object alloc] init]`
will make `myobject` point to another object.

Comment: it even saves you from having more object instances on stack in case you do  
myobject1 = alloc init

myobject2 = alloc init

you would need stack space for each such object pointer

Answer (score 5):

This is safe to do.

The reason is that `myObject` is *not* an object, it's a reference (or pointer if you want to be exact) to the object. That means you've got 2 completely independent objects, but you forget about the reference to the first.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with that.  That is how you make sure you don't leak your first object.

However, you are not technically allocating the released object again. You are just using the old pointer again.

```
Object * myObject = [[Object alloc]init];
myObject = [[Object alloc]init];
```

will result in leaking the first object you created.

Comment: It was the first way I was taught by the Big Nerd Ranch books.

Comment: u can use [[[object alloc] init] autorelease] in case u dont wish to remember releasing important memory.

Answer (score 1):

yes of course. this technique is specially useful in local method variables where you can reuse the object declared once by reallocating it again as new object..!!